# How to add version details to .exe or .dll through cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, g++, cmake

I want to add some version information to `exe` when `compile`.

On vs2008, I can do it through `add->resource->version` steps.

But how can I do it through `cmake`?

Comment: Have you tried adding the resource file to the CMake source list for your exe or dll?

Answer (score 4):

When using MinGW (GCC for Windows), we use windres like so:

```
windres foo.rc foores.o
gcc -o foo.exe foo.o foores.o
```

Refer its documentation [here (MinGW)](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MS_resource_compiler)

With Visual Studio, you might use the Resource Compiler. Refer to its documentation [here (Microsoft)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Resource Files (.rc) are where you will store your version/author information. Refer to the format of the .rc files in Microsoft's documentation linked to above.

A sample .rc files goes something like this:

```
1 VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 1,0,0,0
 PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,0
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x17L
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x4L
 FILETYPE 0x1L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "080904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "Comments", "Addition Library"
            VALUE "CompanyName", "Lithiumheads Inc."
            VALUE "FileDescription", "A library to perform addition."
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1, 0, 0, 0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "Addition"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "2011 Anurag Chugh"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "Addition.dll"
            VALUE "ProductName", "Addition Library"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1, 0, 0, 0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x809, 1200
    END
END
```

Comment: You can call the Resource Compiler from CMake